# Nodejs Redis Scan not returning all items

Tags: node.js, node-redis

I already checked other related responses and I believe I am doing everything right, however it's not returning all the keys, any ideas what might be causing this issue?

My scan method:

```
module.exports.scan = async(pattern, amountPerScan) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


  let cursor = '0';
  let keys = [];
  function scan(){    
    redisClient.scan(cursor, 'MATCH', pattern, 'COUNT', amountPerScan, function(err, reply){
      if(err){
          reject(err);
      }
      cursor = reply[0];
      const keysScan = reply[1];

      if(keysScan.length){
        keys = keys.concat(keysScan);
      }

      if(cursor === '0') {
          return resolve(keys);
      } else {          
          return scan();
      }
    });
  }
  scan();
});
```

And here is my execution:

```
      const allItems = [];
      for(let i = 0; i != 100; i++){        
        allItems.push(redisCache.set('abc.'+i, 'test'));
      }
      
      await Promise.all(allItems);

      redisCache.scan('abc.*', '5').then((keys) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(keys));
      });
```

And here is the keys response:

["abc.22","abc.91","abc.38","abc.44","abc.61","abc.28","abc.54","abc.13","abc.93","abc.99","abc.4","abc.64"]

Only 12 elements when it was suppose to be 100.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid error, I was not awaiting on the call:

```
redisCache.scan('abc.*', '5').then((keys) => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(keys));
});
```

should be:

```
await redisCache.scan('abc.*', '5').then((keys) => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(keys));
});
```